# MultiSelectField vs separate model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, django-model-field

I'm building a directory of Hospitals and Clinics and as a speciality field I'd like to store the speciality or type of clinic or hospital (like Dermathologist, etc.). However, there are some places, specially big ones, with many different specialities in one place, and as the `choices=` method of a `CharField` doesn't allow me to select more than one option I had to think of an alternative.

At first I didn't think it was necessary to create a different table and add a relation, that's why I tried the [django-multiselectfield](https://pypi.org/project/django-multiselectfield/) package and it works just fine, but I was wondering if it would be better to create a different table and give it a relation to the Hospitals model. That 'type' or 'speciality' table once built it likely won't ever change in its contents. Is it better to build a different table performance-wise?

Also I'm trying to store the `choices` of the model in a different `choices.py` file with `TextChoices` model classes as I will be using the same choices in various fields of different models through different apps. I know is generally better to store the choices inside the same class, but does that make sense in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Performance is probably not the primary concern here; I think the difference between the two approaches would be negligible. Whether one or more than one model would use the same set of choices doesn't lean one way or another; either a fixed list or many-to-many relation could accommodate that.

Although you say that the selections aren't expected to change (an argument in favor of a hard-coded list of choices), medical specialties are a kind of data that do change in the long run. Contrast this with, say, months of the year or days of the week, which are a lot less likely to change.

That said, if you already have a multi-select field working, I'd be inclined to leave it alone until there's a compelling reason to change it.

Answer (score 0):

For that 2nd part, I see no issue with storing the Choice list in another .py file.
I've done that strictly to keep my models.py looking somewhat pretty- I don't want to scroll past 150 choices to double check a model method.

The 1st part is all about taste. I'd personally go the Relation + Many-To-Many route.
I always plan for edge cases so "likely won't change" = "So there's a possibility"
Also I like that the Relation + Many-To-Many route doesn't have a dependency, it's a Core Django feature.. It's pretty rock solid and future proof
an added benefit is making it another table also means that a non-technical person could potentially add new options and **in theory** you're not spending your time constantly changing it.